# SML: Operator ```::``` is it true that is right assosiative and shoud be used as ```<value of type a>::<list with elements of type a>```?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Okay so I am a little confused about the cons operator : `::`
I know this is acceptable:

```
   > [2]
   or this
   2::[2,4]
   > [2,2,4]
and i know this is forbbiden
   [2]::[3]
it won't work.
but I recently found out that :
  [2]::[3]::nil
will work :
 > [[2],[3]]
or 
 [2]::[] will do as well.
 >[[2]]
```

My question is why?
I was thinking , maybe it's a rule like if i have a list of type a then with operator cons I can only create a new list of type a.
So for example when I have

> [2] :: [3]
> My lists have elements of type int but I am asking to concatenate into an int list a non init value [3] ??
> But when I have [2]::[3]::[] , the empty list [] could be an empty list of any type so here I need it to be an empty list, with elements  like [3], so it adds to the nil the element [3] and then the element [2] and so on ...
> So is that the reason? Is there something else?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SML, lists are defined as follows:

```
datatype 'a list = nil | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

In particular, `::` is an infix constructor of type `'a * 'a list -> 'a list`.

The syntax `[1, 2, 3]` is sugar for `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: nil`.

You need not only construct lists containing `int`s (i.e., where `'a = int`); for example, you could have list *containing* `int list`s, i.e. an `int list list`. That's what you created:

```
[2] :: [3] :: nil
(* can be sugared as *)
[[2], [3]]
```

(Similarly, you could pick `'a = string` and create the list `"hello" :: "world" :: nil`, i.e. `["hello", "world"]`.)

---

If you want to append two lists, you can use infix `@`, which has type `'a list * 'a list -> 'a list`. For example:

```
[1, 2] @ [3]
(* evaluates to [1, 2, 3] *)
```